# How to call js singleton from an external .js file

Tags: javascript, singleton

```
/*
./main.js
./js/singleton.js
*/


// main.js
const Singleton = require('./js/singleton.js);

// Singelton.Singelton is undefined.
var singleton = Singleton.Singleton.getInstance();
singleton.foo(); // code aint getting this far though.


/*######################################################*/

//singelton.js
exports.Singleton = function() {
    this.instance = null;
    this.getInstance = function() {
        if (this.instance == null)
            this.instance = new Singleton();
        return this.instance;
    }
    this.foo = function() {
        // I believe it's magic
    }
}
```

This sums up what I am trying to do, I had no luck looking for solutions to my problem online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `singelton`? Did you mean `Singleton`? What are your errors?

Comment: The error is // Singelton.Singelton is undefined. I provided a solution, rather trivial. So now that I've corrected the semantics and the syntax, I am happy that you provide spelling checks too.

Comment: It is hard to someone helps you if you do not tell what are your errors in the question. Besides, if the spelling is wrong, people will not find your questions/answers when doing searches!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in the pattern it was in main
I did :
    console.log(Queue.Queue);
And got this {Queue : [function]}
Which implied that Queue was a function.
Changing from :

```
Singelton.Singelton.getInstance();
// to
Singelton.Singelton().getInstnace();
```

Worked just fine.